# How to create new core in Solr 5?

Tags: solr, lucene

Currently we are using *Apache Solr 4.10.3* OR ***H***eliosearch **D**istribution for **S**olr [HDS] as a search engine to index our data.

Now after that, I got the news about *Apache Solr 5.0.0* release in last month. I'd successfully installed *Apache Solr 5.0.0* version and now its running properly on `8983` port (means only running solr but unable to create core). In that UI, I'm unable to find the example core as well as schema or config files under it. So, I started creating new core as we create in old versions but unable to create one. Following is the error, I'm getting it:

> Error CREATEing SolrCore 'testcore1': Unable to create core [testcore1] Caused by: Could not find configName for collection testcore1 found:null

**Note:** I also seen **Cloud** tab on (ie. http://localhost:8983/solr/) left side of Solr UI and also don't know how it works? Meaning I don't know the location of the `schema.xml`, `solrconfig.xml` files due to lack of example folder (**Collection1**) and how to update those files?

Is there any useful document or solution available to solve this error?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Solr 5, creation of cores is supported by the bin/solr script provided in the distribution. Try

```
bin/solr create -help
```

for a quick introduction.

From the above help doc, you may find:

```
bin/solr create [-c name] [-d confdir] [-n configName] [-shards #] [-replicationFactor #] [-p port]
```

Comment: Thanks. Now core is created but I'm unable to see schema.config file in that directory. How to update my existing file with newer one?? Also I don't know about cloud in solr UI??

Comment: I'm unable to find that files on your provided path in solr5. Have you checked solr5?

Comment: {SOLR_INSTALLATION}/server/webapps/solr/{CORE_NAME}/conf/ 
Correction*

Comment: still not able to get the files. Actually, I see the `solr.war` file at `{SOLR_INSTALLATION}/server/webapps/` location. That is no "solr" folder exists at `{SOLR_INSTALLATION}/server/webapps/`.

Comment: You can also check the path in UI. http://localhost:[PORT]/solr/[CORE] should reflect the location of the core.

Comment: `solr create [-c name]` this command only worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In Solr 5.4.0 , create new core using command from Solr-5.x.x folder (Solr Installation folder) like following,

```
$ bin/solr create -c <name>
```

See this documentation of Apache Solr 5.4 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr

Comment: It is showing following error : ERROR: C:\solr\server\solr\configsets not found!

Answer (score 5):

```
{SOLR_INSTALLATION}/server/solr/configsets\basic_configs\conf
```

you can find the example `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml`.
if you want to create the new core
`{SOLR_INSTALLATION}/server/solr/{new core name}` folder and create conf folder with required schema and solrconfig.xml and blank `core.properties` file.
you can find the examples for schema and config in

```
{SOLR_INSTALLATION}/example/example-DIH/solr
```

Answer (score 3):

Create using the web interface
Go to bin directory and issue

```
   ./solr start -e cloud -noprompt
```

Which will start solr.
Go to http://localhost:8983
(this is assuming you are running on localhost)

Click on core admin and they "Add Core"

Answer (score 0):

Use provided `solr` script with `solr` user privileges to create Solr cores, e.g.

```
cd /opt/solr
sudo -u solr ./bin/solr create -c testcore1
```

Run `bin/solr --help` for syntax guidance.

For any other issues, please check your Solr logs (e.g. `/var/solr/logs/solr.log`).

Related: [SOLR-7826: Permission issues when creating cores with bin/solr as root user](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7826).

Answer (score 0):

You can find your solrconfig.xml and schema.xml inside the collection directory.
Go to  /usr/lib/ambari-infra-solr/server/solr and u will see a folder with same name as of collection and with schema and config files.
Inside the conf folder there will be a managed-schema file and other files that you have been searching for.

As for this error
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'testcore1': Unable to create core [testcore1] Caused by: Could not find configName for collection testcore1 found:null
This error must be coming when you are creating solr collection from UI.
For that go to location where solr.cmd is located and type the below code
./solr create -c  -d  -s  -r

Answer (score 0):

copy `conf` from `solr/example/conf to solr/server/solr/`.