# In Solr5.5, easiest command-line way to create core in localhost using existing conf

Tags: solr

I have a git repository containing a `solr/conf` folder with `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml`.  I've managed to create a local solr core and copy these files into it, but I expect there is an easier way than what I did, which was basically:

```
solr create -c mycorename
cp solr/conf/schema.xml /usr/local/Cellar/solr/5.5.0/server/solr/mycorename/conf
cp solr/conf/solrconfig.xml /usr/local/Cellar/solr/5.5.0/server/solr/mycorename/conf
```

...and restart the core to have the changes take effect.

My solution is not that complicated, but it requires a lot of specific knowledge of folders etc. and I'd like something simpler.  Ideally, I would prefer that the core is created in-place in my existing folder.

If that is not possible I would like to have a simpler way that does not require knowledge of the specific solr folders on a developer's workstation.  Maybe a couple of curl commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create new core in Solr 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070505/how-to-create-new-core-in-solr-5)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about best practice for creating a core from command line.

You already use

```
 bin\solr create -c mycorename`
```

but at time you need a restart, because you change the config after creation.

Solr can copy your config files and [creating the core](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Start+Script+Reference#SolrStartScriptReference-Create) in one step:

```
 bin\solr create_core -c mycore -d c:/tmp/myconfig
```

If you are using SolrCloud you could work even more folder independent:

1. Add [configuration folder to zookeeper](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files?focusedCommentId=55155405#UsingZooKeepertoManageConfigurationFiles-UploadingconfigsusingzkcliorSolrJ)
2. [Create collection with this configuration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api1)

see also [How to create new core in Solr 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070505/how-to-create-new-core-in-solr-5)

Comment: This only works when there are more files in the config.  In mine, I had only the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml, and the -d flag does not work in that scenario.  There must be some minimum set of files that is required for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

To create Solr core, use `solr` script ran with [`solr` user privileges](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7826), e.g.

```
sudo -u solr ./bin/solr create -c mycorename
```